# Mod_rewrite delete parameter in 301 Redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, querystring

How would I go about rewriting:

```
http://www.example.com/foo.html?order=desc&limit=all&something=else
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/foo.html?order=desc&something=else
```

I want to remove all instances on `limit=all` regardless of how many other parameters in the url.

I have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)&limit=all(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$ /foo\.html\?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: It simply isn't working. Nothing in the URL changes.

Comment: What is the actual problem/error you are having? You've stated that you tried something, and it didn't do what you expected; but you haven't specified why it was wrong. Offhand you might want to rethink those ampersands unless you're sure there will always be parameters before and after the "limit" parameter. Also you didn't mention "RewriteEngine On"

Comment: As I stated, the rewrite is not doing anything. No errors. Everything just stays the same. I am sure that there will always be parameters either side of the limit parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more playing around I was able to achieve this with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)limit=all\&(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$ http://www.example.com/foo\.html?$1%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks to [Chris S](https://serverfault.com/users/33417/chris-s) for the suggestion to remove the ampersands

Answer (score 0):

You have `^(.*&)&limit=all(&.*)?$` which expects two ampersands in a row before limit.

Since you're certain that you'll always have parameters on both sides of the limit=all, change it to `^(.*&)limit=all&(.*)$`